# Meteor - reactive template value not from database

Tags: meteor

I would like to have a template value {{abc}} that is reactive to changes triggered by other code in my application, but it is not a database field. I have seen the Session variable being used for this but is this the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at meteor [documentation with examples](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency).

From there:

```
var weather = "sunny";
var weatherDep = new Deps.Dependency;

var getWeather = function () {
  weatherDep.depend()
  return weather;
};

var setWeather = function (w) {
  weather = w;
  // (could add logic here to only call changed()
  // if the new value is different from the old)
  weatherDep.changed();
};
```

So everytime you call `setWeather()` the dependency in `getWeather()` will be flagged as changed and call any reactive functions to run again with the new value.